# how to find color code like '&HFFFF0000' format in photoshop?

Tags: colors, photoshop, color-scheme

I am working with aspjpeg component. there the color mentioned like &HFFFF0000 for red etc. How can I get a particular color code in this format?

Answer (score 0):

That is a RGB code color. But I don't really get your point. If you are asking to change the color manually or select the color and then get the code. In both cases click on the black/white box is (left toolbar), select the color and you will see a little box where it shows you the code, or if you want to put a color manually write the code there and it will take you directly to the color.

Hope it helps.